# why following error is occurred when i am trying to read image file by imread?

Tags: matlab

I have to concatenate the path and file name but the following error is coming as given below:

```
    path = 'E:\Ob_Extraction\peta\PETA dataset\3DPeS\archive\';
    allFiles = dir( 'E:\Ob_Extraction\peta\PETA dataset\3DPeS\archive' );
    allNames = { allFiles.name };
    image = imread(strcat(path,allNames(3)));
```

Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 457)

The file name or URL argument must be a string.

Error in imread (line 316)

[filename, fmt_s, extraArgs] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

how do i solve it ?

Comment: Try `allNames{3}` instead of the round brackets, I think it's trying to concatenate a string and a cell currently.

Comment: thank you, my problem is resolved